# can i use -> in c? that bring me an error

Tags: c

i wrote this code for the university its an exercise to practice lists and sublists and i can't run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodito{
    int dato;
    struct nodito *sig;}nodito;

typedef struct nodito * Sublista;

typedef struct nodo{
    char nombre[10];
    Sublista sub;
    struct nodo *sig;}nodo;

typedef struct nodo *TLista;

void cargoL(TLista *L){
    FILE *arch;
    TLista nuevo,ant,act;
    Sublista nuevito;
    arch=fopen("texto.txt","rt");
    if (arch==NULL){
        printf("archivo no existe \n");
    }
    else{
        while(!feof(arch)){
            nuevo=(TLista)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            fscanf(arch,"%s %d",(nuevo->nombre),& (nuevo->sub->dato));
            if ( *L==NULL || strcmp((*L)->nombre,nuevo->nombre)>0){
                nuevo->sig=*L;
                *L=nuevo;
                nuevo->sub->sig=NULL;
            }
            else{
                ant=NULL;
                act=*L;
                while ( act!=NULL && strcmp(act->nombre,nuevo->nombre)<=0){
                    ant=act;
                    act=act->sig;
                }
                if (act!=NULL && strcmp(act->nombre,nuevo->nombre)==0){
                    nuevito=(Sublista)malloc(sizeof(nodito));
                    nuevito->dato=nuevo->sub->dato;
                    free(nuevo);
                    nuevito->sig=act->sub;
                    act->sub=nuevito;
                }
                else{
                    ant->sig=nuevo;
                    nuevo->sig=act;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(arch);
}
```

the line `nuevo->sub->sig=NULL` bring me an error
same for `fscanf(arch,"%s %d",(nuevo->nombre),& (nuevo->sub->dato))`

can i use the double ->?
is that the problem?
can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show us what the errors are?

Comment: Don't you think it would make sense to tell us what error you are getting?

Comment: `nuevo=(TLista)malloc(sizeof(nodo));` and `nuevo->sub->sig=NULL;` You are not allocating memory for `sub`. Same for second parameter of `fscanf(arch,"%s %d",(nuevo->nombre),& (nuevo->sub->dato))`

Comment: how i allocate memory for sub?

Comment: sub is inside nodo

Comment: @JuanFedericoDiLeo check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocated memory for `nuevo` using `malloc`, but you never allocated memory for `sub` inside `nuevo`.

You tried dereferencing it in `fscanf` and the statement where you set it to `NULL`.

A simple fix would be to allocate space for `sub` as

```
nuevo->sub = malloc(sizeof(*Sublista));
```

Both your errors should disappear now.
Do remember to free sub *before* you free nuevo.

Comment: Great! Add `free(nuevo->sub);` before `free(nuevo);` too. Else it will lead to memory leak.